# VS Code opening the window to the app, but doesn't show anything and immediately closes. How to fix?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just started using Visual Studio Code and it just won't work at all. I've tried both the insider version and the stable. I've tried using CMD to open it, and have tried the verbose command as well as a few others.

It won't let me post the codes I used for some reason, so I can't show some of them. This however is the primary error that I keep being given when I try to launch from CMD:

[main 2023-09-06T13:08:21.658Z] update#setState idle
[16672:0906/090822.378:ERROR:electron_api_utility_process.cc(123)] Failed to create null handle: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)

It's frustrating me. My friend even tried to give me the exact same folders his VS code is using thinking it was a faulty file, but it still didn't work. I don't know what to do.

I'm at my wits end here. Anyone can help? I can't find anyone else having or fixing this problem.

Tried to open from command prompt, downloaded older versions, downloaded code insiders, downloaded the stable version, have tried deleting all folders associated with VS code, have tried putting in established folders from a friend's computer, have tried turning off firewall, along with many other attempts. Tried turning the computer off and on. Nothing works.

Some things make the VS code window have text appear, others just show a blank window. It doesn't even show up in task manager. It opens then immediately shuts down.

Comment: Seems like you are not alone: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/185298 Unfortunately there is no solution for this?!

Comment: No clue. I legit need this for my student course. I can't get it to work outside of the web browser version which is just inconvenient

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. Does this happen with you run it with `--disable-extensions`? What do you mean by "post the codes"?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the [nul serivce](https://revertservice.com/10/null/) to create `utility process`.

a super simple test command from here:

> `echo >nul`

will be failed with the same error.

Based on my experience, some stripped-down versions of Windows may lack the `null.sys` file, preventing proper activation, or they may have the `null.sys` file but still fail to start the `NUL` service.

For the former case, you would need to find a `null.sys` file that matches your system and replace it accordingly. However, for the latter case, you can easily configure it using the following command from `cmd.exe`:

- `sc query null` // check if the service was runnning ?
- `sc start null` // start it
- `sc create null binPath= C:\Windows\System32\drivers\null.sys type= kernel start= auto error= normal` // create null service according [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-create)

Please refer to my [response here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/185298#issuecomment-1736864708) for more details and principles.

**Refs:**

1. https://ss64.com/nt/nul.html
2. https://ss64.com/nt/sc.html
3. https://revertservice.com/10/null/
4. https://siebn.de/other/nulldevice/

Answer (score 1):

we meet the same bug and it's rare enough.Have you try to use specified older version?1.61 or even older?
Up to now I have had to use the 1.61.
my friend tell me that maybe only reinstall windows 10 can finally solve it,but it's tiresome.

Comment: Oh dang. That actually worked. So it's something with the new versions of VS code. That's interesting. Thank you for this knowledge, not a permanent fix but it works for now

Comment: yes at least it can work, new vscode has sandbox frame,maybe that's problem come from,because others have same situation can fix it with command '--no-sandbox',though   it doesn't work in a few computers like you and me....

Comment: Can you try to catch bug report in that issue ?https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/185298

Comment: please follow the instructions in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/185298#issuecomment-1710972153 and submit a crash dump in that same issue ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently updating your version of Windows can make the problem stop happening. Perhaps it has to do with a specific combination of Windows build versions and VS Code versions. I'm not yet sure exactly what those version ranges and combinations are, but I'll try to find out and update this post.

If you try this and it works for you, please suggest an edit to this post that says what build of Windows you had installed before the update, and what build you updated to. You can check your update history by doing Select Start > Settings > Windows Update > Update history.

---

Someone (who I'm not sure if is a VS Code maintainer but I don't think they are) has done an analysis of one of the contributed crash dumps [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/185298#issuecomment-1736864708), saying that it probably has to do with that user's Windows system missing the [NULL kernel service](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-does-one-run-a-null-service-missing-devnull/7de81856-98a4-4e75-b25e-b287dc2a927f). They give further instructions there about how to check if it exists and create it if it doesn't. I'll inline those instructions here if someone on the VS Code teams confirms it to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem: When I opened VSCode, it was showing the codebase, but after a few seconds it crashed (just closed).

I looked at the logs of VSCode and found in `C:\Users\{YOURUSERNAME}\AppData\Roaming\Code\logs\{THEDATE}\window1\renderer.log` the following error message:

`2024-03-19 22:32:52.418 [error] [Extension Host] (node:16252) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead. (Use` Code --trace-deprecation ... `to show where the warning was created)`

After some research, I found out that the issue is with some faulty VSCode extension.

I navigated to `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions` and deleted the faulty extension.

(BUT BE CAREFUL: DO NOT DELETE IMPORTANT SYSTEM FILES - JUST FAULTY EXTENSION)

After that, VSCode did not crash. I hope this helps.

Comment: which extension was it?

Comment: @starball. It was CMake, but it was some custom extension, not official one