# VS Code opening for .5 second but closes immediatly

Tags: visual-studio-code

So i went on a 2 week vacation. When i came back my vscode just does not want to start. When i try to open it i see it for a brief second and then it immediatly closes again.
No matter what i try it just does not want to work.

Does anyone have any idea what this could be.
Since i have not touched vscode in 2 weeks and it suddenly stopped working i have no clue what it could be.
It also gives me no error so its hard to look up the problem.

I tried:

Reinstalling,
Added code.exe to my anti-virus,
Restart my pc,
Compatibillity mode and disable full screen res,
Opening as admin,

Comment: Open a command window and run the vscode exe from there.  Hopefully there will be some error message that stays on the screen.

Comment: Yup that got me an error:
[main 2023-09-23T22:53:34.089Z] update#setState idle
[main 2023-09-23T22:53:34.434Z] vscode-file: Refused to load resource e:\Visual Studio Code\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\theme-seti\icons\seti.woff from vscode-file: protocol (original URL: vscode-file://vscode-app/e:/Visual%20Studio%20Code/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/extensions/theme-seti/icons/seti.woff)
[23340:0924/005334.553:ERROR:electron_api_utility_process.cc(123)] Failed to create null handle: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)

Comment: Is your system configured to auto-update? Because maybe your VS Code (or Electron or some other component VS Code is dependent on) got auto-updated and now something is incompatible/broken. From your error, looks like it's related to a theme, looks like a custom theme. You could try doing a complete uninstall (as in removing all residual files)

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77052452/11107541. please follow the instructions in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/185298#issuecomment-1710972153 and submit a crash dump in that same issue ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found out what caused this problem.

Since i disabled automatic windows updates i have to manually check which package i want to update.

So just check if your windows is up to date. After i updated windows it worked again!

Comment: do you remember what specific build of windows you had before you updated? You can check: Select Start  > Settings  > Windows Update  > Update history. And what build did you update to?

Comment: I updated to: 2023-KB5030180 cumulatieve update voor .NET Framework 3.5, 4.8 en 4.8.1 voor Windows 10 versie 22H2, 
2023—KB5030211 (OS Builds 19044.3448 and 19045.3448)
This fixed it for me